# Distributing objects in boxes

Tags: combinatorics

In how many way can we distribute:  7 objects in 3 boxes;
provided that:
1) objects are distinct, boxes are distinct and boxes may be empty;
2) objects are distinct, boxes are distinct and boxes may not be
empty;
3) objects are identical, boxes are distinct and boxes may be empty;
4) objects are identical, boxes are identical and boxes may not be
empty;
5) objects are distinct, boxes are identical and boxes may be empty;
6) objects are distinct, boxes are identical and boxes may not be
empty.

(I should provide all this 6 options)

Comment: This may be helpful: http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~vadim/teaching/579/s12/Counting.pdf

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be (temporarily) closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/xQWVb) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Some pointers:

1. For each object you must make a $3$-way choice of box; there are $7$ objects, and the choices are independent, so there are $3^7$ ways to make them.
2. Start with the answer to (1) and subtract the unwanted distributions. You’ll want an [inclusion-exclusion argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for this.
3. This is a standard [stars-and-bars problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29); the linked article has both a formula for the answer and a reasonably explanation of why the formula is correct.
4. This is the number of [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of $7$ into $3$ parts. You can find it most easily by brute force.
5. This is ${7\brace 3}+{7\brace 2}+{7\brace 1}$; see (6) below.
6. This is $7\brace 3$, a [Stirling number of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). These numbers satisfy a nice recurrence, so $n\brace k$ is not hard to compute for small $n$ and $k$.